# How to returns a dataframe according to a date column condition

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a dataframes for example :

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Date": ["2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03"], "List": ["A0", "A1", "A2"],
     "Status": ["B0", "B1", "B2"], "Type": ["E", "S", "S"]}
)

List = pd.DataFrame(
    { "List": ["A0", "A1", "A2"],"Type_List": ["E", "S", "S"]}
)

Status = pd.DataFrame(
    { "Status": ["B0", "B1", "B2"],"Type_Status": ["E", "S", "S"]}
)
```

I have a **DF** dataframe that I try to merge with **List** and **Status** according to conditions :

If DF Date < "2021-10-01" do:

```
final_df = DF.set_index('Status').join(Status[Status['Type_Status'] == 'E'].set_index('Status'), 
                                         how='left')
final_df = final_df.reset_index().set_index('List').join(List.drop_duplicates().set_index('List'),
                                                          how='left', rsuffix='df2')
final_df = final_df.reset_index()
final_df['Type'] = final_df['Type_Status'].fillna(final_df.Type_List)
```

If DF Date > "2021-10-01" do:

```
final_df2 = DF.merge(Status, on="Status")
final_df2 ['Type'] = final_df2['Type_Status']
```

And finally concatenates final_df & final_df2 to return a final dataframe

How to make a condition according to the date column of my dataframe **DF** and make my code more correct ?

Comment: `Type_Status` column doesn't exist.

Comment: @CeliusStingher oh sorry I corrected it thank you

Comment: @wysouf in words, you try to replace the Type column of your DF with the Type columns of Status or List (depending on the conditions shown)? will you need the Type_status and Type_List in the output?

Comment: @Ben.T yes yes in words exactly, no I don't need the Type_status and Type_List in the output

Answer (score 0):

Given you are working with 2 dataframes, one for the dates before 2021-10-01 and another one for the dates following it, I suggest using `pd.to_datetime()` and then slicing your dataframe instead of using an if/else.

```
DF['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

final_df = DF[DF['Date'] <' 2021-10-01'].set_index('Status').join(Status[Status['Type_Status'] == 'E'].set_index('Status'), 
                                         how='left')
final_df = final_df.reset_index().set_index('List').join(List.drop_duplicates().set_index('List'),how='left', rsuffix='df2').reset_index()
final_df['Type'] = final_df['Type_Status'].fillna(final_df.Type_List)
```

And as for the the second dataframe:

```
final_df2 = DF[DF['Date'] >= '2021-10-01'].merge(Status,on="Status")
final_df2['Type'] = final_df2['Type_Status']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) as you work on only one column. Create a mask for the Date and `map` the columns Status and List from DF with the corresponding dataframe. Then use np.where depending on your conditions

```
# new input with all possible cases and change Type values to see the difference
DF = pd.DataFrame( # 3 dates less than the threshold, one meeting the Stauts==E criteria
    {"Date": ["2021-10-01","2021-10-01","2021-10-01", "2021-10-02", "2021-10-03"],
     "List": ["A0", "A1", "A2","A1", "A2"], "Status": ["B0", "B1", "B2","B1", "B2"], 
     "Type": ["B"]*5}
)
print(DF)
#          Date List Status Type
# 0  2021-10-01   A0     B0    B this one will meet the Status==E criteria
# 1  2021-10-01   A1     B1    B this one will be List['A1']
# 2  2021-10-01   A2     B2    B ...
# 3  2021-10-02   A1     B1    B this one with Date greater, then Status mapping
# 4  2021-10-03   A2     B2    B

# Note I changed all type values to see where the result comes from
List = pd.DataFrame( 
    { "List": ["A0", "A1", "A2"],"Type_List": ["I", "A", "S"]}
)
Status = pd.DataFrame(
    { "Status": ["B0", "B1", "B2"],"Type_Status": ["E", "J", "K"]}
)
```

Here is the code to get the new Types

```
# mask and mapping List and Status
maskDate = pd.to_datetime(DF['Date']) <= '2021-10-01'
mapStatus = DF['Status'].map(Status.set_index('Status')['Type_Status'])
mapList = DF['List'].map(List.drop_duplicates().set_index('List')['Type_List'])

DF['newType'] = np.where( # you can reassign to Type directly
    maskDate, #condition on the Date
    # when the Date is less equal 2021-10-01
    # then use mapStatus and keep only the Status==E
    # fill the other with the mapping from List
    mapStatus.where(mapStatus.eq('E'), other=mapList),
    # if date greater then 2021-10-01
    mapStatus
)
print(DF)
#          Date List Status Type newType
# 0  2021-10-01   A0     B0    B       E
# 1  2021-10-01   A1     B1    B       A
# 2  2021-10-01   A2     B2    B       S
# 3  2021-10-02   A1     B1    B       J
# 4  2021-10-03   A2     B2    B       K
```

Ultimately, you can do even more simple, same resut

```
DF['newTypeV2'] = mapStatus.mask(maskDate & mapStatus.ne('E'), other=mapList)
```